# Prevent function from executing twice

Tags: jquery, function

I'm making my own function for the first time `$.fn.testing = function(){....}`;

But i'm having a problem that I'm not able to solve yet. The next scenario isn't smart, but It might happen, so that's the reason why I want to fix it so the user doesn't have to:

```
$('.target').testing("message" : "Hello!");
$('#test .target').testing("message" : "Hello world!");
```

The function will make the 'message' pop-up. So what the user wants here is that, for every `.target` there has to be an pop-upbox with "Hello!" and if this `.target` also has an id of `#test` then it should pop-up: "Hello world!". But the problem is, that now the script will pop-up "Hello!" AND "Hello world!" when the `.target#test` is triggered.

So what I want in my function is that the function sees if the function is already called on this object, and if it is it has to `.unbind()` the previous function and then continues to add the function.

How can I achieve this? Hopefully my explanation is clear enough!

(The example above is a little bit simplified, so please don't comment on the use of it)

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do this:

```
var _myFunction = function() {
  alert($(this).data("message"));
};
```

in plugin do something like this

```
jQuery.fn.testing = function(msg) {
    this
        .data("message", msg)
        .unbind('click', _myFunction)
        .bind('click', _myFunction);
};
```

**EDIT:** here is an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QKdqg/)

Comment: ur wellcome... glad it helped (:

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$('.target#test').testing("message" : "Hello world!");
$('.target:not(#test)').testing("message" : "Hello!");
```

EDIT - do you mean something like this?

```
$('.target').testing(function(e){
   if (this.id === 'event'){
        alert('hello world');
   }else{
        alert('hello');
   }
});
```

Comment: That is indeed really helpfull, but then the user has to specify this. Is there a way of doing this inside the function?

Comment: I´ve edited the main post, see the code bit, how would you achieve it now? Thanks for youre answer by the way, if there is no possible way of achieving this inside the function then I'll use this! Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed example?Like showing us the code of your function otherwise we can't understand correctly what you are trying to achiev. Maybe post an example on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thanks for youre help. I have figgured it out already (see my answer below). But still thanks for youre effort!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $this. msg;
$('.target').each(function(){
  $this = $(this);

  if((#this.attr("id) != "#test") || ($this.find("#test").length == 0))//here check for all the possible ids you want){
      msg = "message" : "Hello world!";  
  }
  else{
      msg = "message" : "Hello!";
  }
  $this.testing(msg);
});
```

Comment: that would indeed work, but I want it to happen inside the function itself. This is just a simple example, but if it gets more advanced you'll might have to use something like: `$('.target').filter(":not(#test #test1 #test2 #test3 #test4 #test5 #test6 #test7 #test8 #test9 #test10 etc)").testing("message" : "Hello!");
` I´ve edited the main post, see the code bit, how would you achieve it now? Thanks for youre answer btw!

Comment: Thanks that would indeed help but if the `id` was a child of the `$(this)` it wouldn't. I wasn't really precise in the question, sorry for that. But i'd figgured it out already. Thanks for youre help!

Comment: that would indeed work! Thanks for youre help. But just adding `$(this).unbind()` is easier, so I'll use that :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood: For example you have a popup on target appended to target element and now the popup is a child to target, or may be you could have implemented otherwise. My point is to whenever a call to the function is made it will check if the popup is inserted into DOM. If it is first it would remove that popup and then insert a new one with new message.

I mean Like...

```
    function() {
        //if a pop is present
        $('.popup').remove();

        var msg = $(this).attr('title'); //for example
        var popup = "html containin msg...";
        $(this).append(popup);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! But I already have it. Thanks for helping though

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the right way to do it, but I figgured it out myself. It was very easy, just add `$(this).unbind()` in the beginning of youre own function. It will remove all previously added functions and still continues to add the current one. I had tried it before but with an extra selector: `$(this).unbind(".testing")`, that didn't work for some reason but now I have it working.

Thanks for youre answers and youre help! Really appreciate it!